# Search Paths Problems

Tags: objective-c, xcode, search, path

I am currently working on a project that I often move the project to different computers. Everytime I do it says that its missing files when they are clearly in the project folder. I was told this is to do with the search paths. Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all paths that are set in your Project are not absolute paths, but relative to **$(SRCROOT)**

Got to the Project --> Build Settings and check the *Search Paths* section. In the screenshot below, the bottom Entry for example is NOT relative to the Project and could potentially cause problems if someone else would try to compile the project when they have not installed Reveal

[image: Xcode Searchpath Settings]